# PHP/MySQL How do I remove duplicate information from a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am trying to generate a simple list from a series of tables in a MySQL database. The SQL I am using is:

```
$resource_sql = "SELECT prod_spec_sheets.spec_uri, prod_spec_sheets.spec_title, 
prod_photos.photo_uri, prod_photos.photo_title, 
prod_diagrams.diag_uri, prod_diagrams.diag_title, 
prod_ies.ies_uri, prod_ies.ies_title, 
prod_instruction_sheets.instr_sheet_uri, prod_instruction_sheets.instr_sheet_title
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN prod_spec_sheets ON products.prod_id = prod_spec_sheets.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_photos ON products.prod_id = prod_photos.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_diagrams ON products.prod_id = prod_diagrams.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_ies ON products.prod_id = prod_ies.prod_id
LEFT JOIN prod_instruction_sheets ON products.prod_id = prod_instruction_sheets.prod_id 
WHERE products.prod_code = '$product_code'";
```

The PHP I am using to display it looks like this:

```
     if ($resource_num_rows > 1){
  echo '<h2>Downloads</h2>';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "<ul>";
$count = 0;
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  if ($count % 2) {
    echo '">' . $value . '</a></li>' . PHP_EOL;
  } else {
    echo '<li><a href="' . RESOURCES_URI . $value;
  }
  $count++;
}
echo "</ul>";
  }
}
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://URL/ss_pil.pdf">Specs</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pic_pil.jpg">Photo</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pd_pil.TIF">Diagram</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/is_pil.pdf">Instructions</a></li>
</ul><ul><li><a href="http://URL/ss_pil.pdf">Specs</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pic_pil.jpg">Photo</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pd_pil.TIF">Diagram</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/isu_pil.pdf">Instructions (ALT)</a></li>
</ul>
```

When what I really need is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://URL/ss_pil.pdf">Specs</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pic_pil.jpg">Photo</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/pd_pil.TIF">Diagram</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/is_pil.pdf">Instructions</a></li>
<li><a href="http://URL/isu_pil.pdf">Instructions (ALT)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each table (except products) could have many items associated with a product, this example only shows what happens if there is more than one set of *instructions* in the **prod_instruction_sheets** table.

I'm not sure if the answer is in a better MySQL statement, or a change in the PHP to my loop. Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

Try to [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) only the field you need and use the keyword [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4279748) in your statement:

```
$resource_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT prod_spec_sheets.spec_uri, prod_spec_sheets.spec_title, 
prod_photos.photo_uri, prod_photos.photo_title, 
prod_diagrams.diag_uri, prod_diagrams.diag_title, 
prod_ies.ies_uri, prod_ies.ies_title, 
prod_instruction_sheets.instr_sheet_uri, prod_instruction_sheets.instr_sheet_title
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN prod_spec_sheets ON products.prod_id = prod_spec_sheets.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_photos ON products.prod_id = prod_photos.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_diagrams ON products.prod_id = prod_diagrams.prod_id 
LEFT JOIN prod_ies ON products.prod_id = prod_ies.prod_id
LEFT JOIN prod_instruction_sheets ON products.prod_id = prod_instruction_sheets.prod_id 
WHERE products.prod_code = '$product_code'";
```

**Edit:**

Ok i see what you are doing, one easy way to filter this column in `PHP` is to put the line you are writting into an associative array and check if you have already write back this data.
Move also your `UL` outside of the `while` loop if you don't have two list.

Example:

```
if ($resource_num_rows > 1){
    echo '<h2>Downloads</h2>' . PHP_EOL . '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    $seen=array(); //use to filter te line written
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            if ($count % 2) {
                $line .= '">' . $value . '</a></li>';

                // check if the line has already been output
                if (!array_key_exists($line, $seen)) {
                    // no mark it as written
                    $seen[$line]=true;

                    // and output the line
                    echo $line . PHP_EOL;
                }
            } else {
                $line='<li><a href="' . RESOURCES_URI . $value;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: All those fields are needed to give the correct response - and DISTINCT doesn't do anything, as it is not a double up in the DB, the double up is (I believe) the correct behaviour of the code, what I need to do is remove the indistinct items from the *second* returned row.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY products.prod_id smells like it should work at first glance.